# RS485 ESP32 half-duplex communication

Tags: communication, esp32

I have a question, so I have two identical devices that I would like to communicate via RX / TX (RS485). Both devices are exactly the same component, but as far as I know this is half-duplex mode, which means the first device sends, the second device receives and then again the second device receives and the first device sends. I have no idea how to write code for this communication. I found here as far as this chip is concerned https://github.com/nopnop2002/SC16IS752 also tried to load on both devices example code https://github.com/nopnop2002/SC16IS752/blob/master/Arduino%20%26%20ESP8266/example/I2C_RECEIVE/I2C_RECEIVE.ino but nothing works. Some ideas?

[image]

Comment: There are some open inputs of U3 SC16IS752IPW, pin2 CTSA,, pin 28 CTSA, pin 27 CDA, pin 26 DTRA, pin25 DTSA. You should read the datasheet of this IC very carefully if it is possible to leave them open.

Answer (score 1):

You need a lot of experience when working with asynchronos serial transmission using RS485. You need also some test equipment. A terminal program for windows using a serial interface of the PC would help to see what is send by the ESP32. You may also send from the terminal program to the ESP32.

[image: terminal program]

If the serial interface of the PC uses RS232 you need a converter to RS485. You need to know how to set the RS485 converter for sending or receiving.

[image: RS232 converter to RS485]

You should know the UART signals RXD, TXD, RTS, CTS, DTR, DSR, DCD and RI. You should know how to set and align baud rate, number of data bits, parity, and number of stop bits. I recommend using a signal indicator for the UART signals with LEDs.

[image: signal indicator]

Start small, take two PCs, run a terminal programm on both, connect the serial interfaces of both and send and receive data between them. You should be able to type some characters on one PC and read them on the other one. You should try it at first using RS232, if everything is ok, try RS485.

IF you are able to exchange serial data between the PCs using RS485, you may connect one PC to one ESP32. You should test output of the ESP32 and see the characters on the PC. Next is ouput from the PC to input into the ESP32.

If you are able to exchange data between PC and ESP32 in both directions you may try the connection of two ESP32. But you should use the PCs now as passive observers to the ESP32.

**I do recommend to start with a very small and simple test.** There is the BEEPER X1 controlled by the signal DTRB at pin 19 of U3. You should be able to set the beeper on and off with your test program. It is not useful do other more complex tests with U3 if this very basic test does not work.

Comment: Is this something like here https://www.mischianti.org/2020/05/11/interface-arduino-esp8266-esp32-rs-485/?

Comment: Some good information at mischanti, but a bad typo: RS458.

Comment: Ok I order few stuffs so I could make tests... few more things if I have data send on one side via RS485 can I simply read it on another side on ESP32 via RX pin witouht any components? So in my case I'm using device from schematic for sending data to pure ESP32 device? And how is with oposite, if I send from ESP32 to device which have RS485? Hope you understand what I'm asking.

Comment: @noname You may connect TX of one side to RX of the other side, but only using the same logic levels on both sides. So output TX with TTL level to input RX TTL. Or both sides with RS232 levels or both RS485. GND of both sides needs to be connected too. Before testing serial transfer you should verify beeper function. Try beeper on, beeper off, beeper pulses periodically.

Comment: After hours of reading I understand I need to set pin to low/high when receiving or transmiting. So I need to set pins (basically one pin for both on RS485 component DE & !RE) to high/low. Those pin is in my case connected to RTSA pin of UART which should do this job automatically based on datasheet, do I need to enable somehow auto RTS? In datasheet it says:This pin only affects the transmit and receive operations when Auto-RTS function is enabled via the Enhanced Features Register (EFR[6]) for hardware flow control operation.
Would be better if I use some of free GPIO pins from UART?

Comment: RS485 direction control should be set before the first bit of the first serial character is send. It should be reset after the last bit of the last character. So this timing depends on baud rate and the number of all bits per character. I recommend to use hardware RTSA control. Don't use some of free GPIO pins from UART under software control. Check the description of all register bits. It may be possible you need a combination of several bits to be set and cleared. Have you tested the beeper with success?

Comment: Another question, when from device A for example data is sent to device B, what would be voltage on RTS pin on UART? If I understand it right device A as transmiter should have on RTS 3,3V and device B as receiver should have RTS voltage 0, also on device A on RS485 should be on TX pin voltage 3,3V on RX 0 and on device B should be voltage on TX pin 0 and RX pin 3,3V. Is this correct?  If this is right than will be easier for me to debuging it because currently is really hard as I have two same devices with same drivers and I don't know if it works right. I will try to use from RS485 from PC.

Comment: @noname beware that at TTL level the signals are inverted. Idle TXs and RXs have logic level 1, and perhaps RTS is the same. U3 marks RTSA as a negated output, and this confuses me a bit. You should confirm that the level of RTSA is correct while transmitting - it seems to me that the RS485 driver wants a "1" on DE in order to transmit. Probably the correct configuration of U3 (auto RTS + invert RTS?, or something similar) should work.

Comment: I got today MAX485 and firstly just try to send data to USB-RS485 from ESP with RS485. That works.

Second I try send data from USB-RS485 to ESP with RS485, that also works.

Than send from one ESP with RS485 to another ESP with RS485, that also works.

So everything is working as it should with USB-RS485 and also between ESPs. So Now I have good debugging tool to find what is wrong on my PCBs. Currently they are by HW dev I will get them back next week and continue.

Comment: What I have measured with voltmeter from MAX485:
DI (TX) on both ESP is 3.3V;
RO (RX) on both ESP is 3.3V;
DE-RE from transmitter is 3.3V;
DE-RE on receiver is 0V

So on my PCBs on receiver I need to measure DE-RE 0V when receiving data from transmitter. There I need to find RTS register which would do this automatically or use some of free GPIO pins to set it manually. Will see when I will get PCBs back. Now its much easier for me, because of understanding how it works in practice.

Also my code, I haven’t need to use any library so in this way should also work on PCBs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you keep the RS485 transceiver in receive mode and when you want to transmit you set it to transmit mode for the duration of the transmission.

Comment: Where I can see some example, how this should be done? I try for example with this code, but doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/3GqXRtNv

Comment: There is no info where and how you connected the RS485 transceiver transmit enable pin.

Comment: How should I define that?

Comment: I don't even which RS485 transceiver you are using, or anything else about your hardware and how they are connected together, except the things you have mentioned. With the scarce information given it is hard to say anything specific.

Comment: I append schematic in post, haven't you see it? SC16IS752 (IO expander) and SN65HVD72 (RS485)

Comment: No I haven't because it was only appended some minutes ago. And the SC16IS752 is not an IO expander, it's an UART. It supports auto RS485 transmitter control and your schematic already connects it. Or you can manually control the handshake pin. Unfortunately the driver is done by random hobbyists and only allows basic functionality, there is no support to set auto RS485 mode or the RTS pin state easily, you need to make such features yourself.

Comment: From where should I start? Is there any example code at last that I know what should I do?

Comment: There are some open inputs of U3 SC16IS752IPW, pin2 CTSA,, pin 28 CTSA, pin 27 CDA, pin 26 DTRA, pin25 DTSA. You should read the datasheet of this IC very carefully if it is possible to leave them open.